# how should I design the neural network model for training

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

Suppose a data has 9 features, and the label is 1 when the value of the third feature is greater than the value of the first feature and the value of the ninth feature is greater than the value of the eighth feature, otherwise the lable would be 0. For such type of dataset, how should we design the neural network model for training in order to have better results?

data like this

5 85 9 6 7 9 3 15 19    label:since 9 > 5 and 19 > 15 then the label is 1

I used a general neural network for training and found that I could not achieve a fit

Answer (score -1):

The architecture of a neural network is a complex question. I recently wanted to make a NN and also struggled with how to implement it properly. Maybe you could provide an example of what you already implemented to give a general idea since "a general neural network" is a bit evasive.

Basically you want to teach a rule to your neural network. By googling this statement I found some articles about it. [At this adress](https://ai.googleblog.com/2022/01/controlling-neural-networks-with-rule.html), [this one](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/learning-rules-in-neural-network/) and [this one](https://data-flair.training/blogs/learning-rules-in-neural-network/). I'm not a specialist but maybe that can help you get a better grasp of your problem.